# Vue.js file error "The file will not be displayed in the editor because it is either binary, very large or uses an unsupported text encoding."

Tags: vue.js, file, visual-studio-code, components, symbols

I was working on a Vuejs project. So this morning when I opened the project it wasn't compiling anymore and it was reporting an error in one of the components. When opening the component, this message appeared in the VSCode editor "The file will not be displayed in the editor because it is either binary, very large or uses an unsupported text encoding." Clicking on open anyway appears a lot of code with strange symbols as shown in the image. When I try to open the file in another editor, the same problem also happens, but the symbols change. I would like to know what might have happened and if there is a way to recover my file?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your file is corrupt. Restore from a backup, or re-pull from git.